# Android - Drop Shadow to Button

Tags: android, button, shadow

How can I drop shadow to Button in Android?

Like that:

https://app-direct-www-cloudfront.s3.amazonaws.com/app_resources/1398/overview/img257128879592909522.png

Thanks you all!

Comment: Please see my answer if it is helping you then please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add shadow to a bitmap as follows:

```
Paint mShadow = new Paint(); 
// radius=10, x-offset = 0, y-offset=2, color=black

mShadow.setShadowLayer(10.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, 0xFF000000); 
// in onDraw(Canvas) 
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0.0f, 0.0f, mShadow);
```

Adding shadow to shapes is similarly achieved.

Comment: Can you please explain the params in setShadowLayer() method. I can't understand them from the official docs.

Comment: @RohanBhatia x/y => distance of the shadow from your shape in x/y coordinates, color is the hexadecimal representation of the color, not sure about radius but I believe it's something to do with the thickness of the shadow. best is to play around with these values to see what each of them does

Comment: Thanks Caner, I found a repo which explained these parameters. Radius does have to do with the blurring of shadow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use 9patch like [this](http://img502.imageshack.us/img502/9394/bblue9.png). Just specify content area via right and bottom lines.